# Do the adverb and adjective together modify the noun?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, modifiers

> The really good golfer is playing well.

I know really modifies good and good modifies golfer, but does the full phrase *really good* modify *golfer*?

> The really big house is for sale.

Does the phrase *really big* modify *house*?

Comment: Different accounts of English grammar use the word "modify" to mean different things; there isn't a single standard. See e.g. [Dependency Grammar v. Constituency Grammar.](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=48725)

Comment: With adverbs like _really_ and _very_ (called "intensifiers" in the trade), yes, that's the way it works. The intensifiers intensify the adjective they modify, and the whole phrase in turn modifies a noun (if it's attributive, and not a predicate adjective -- predicate adjectives don't modify anything). It's  recursive, with the same structure inside and outside. But not all adverbs modify (or intensify) adjectives. They've got dozens of uses.

Comment: Yes, *really good* modifies *golfer*, just as *great* or *excellent* modifies *golfer*.